# Change font size of tooltip text in amcharts

Tags: javascript, typescript, amcharts, amcharts4, amcharts5

I am using `amcharts` in my angular project where I want to change the `font-size` of the tooltip text.

**What I have used(current code):**

```
    const tooltip = am5.Tooltip.new(this.root, {
      getFillFromSprite: false,
      pointerOrientation: 'horizontal',
      tooltipText: 'center',
      labelText: '[#000000]P&L {valueY} \nChange from spot : ({id}%)\nUnderlying: {valueX}',
    });

    tooltip.get('background')?.setAll({
      fill: am5.color(0xffffff),
      stroke: am5.color(0x6771dc),
      strokeWidth: 1,
      fillOpacity: 0.8,
    });
```

I have tried this also...

```
    const tooltip = am5.Tooltip.new(this.root, {
      getFillFromSprite: false,
      pointerOrientation: 'horizontal',
      tooltipText: 'center',
      tooltipHTML: `<span style="font-size:12px;">p&L</span>`,
    });
```

but it's not working, also I am not getting any `official docs` for changing the font size of the text in `tooltip`.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try: `tooltipText: "[fontSize: 40px]{categoryX}[/]: [bold]{valueY}[/]",`  [text-styling](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/formatters/text-styling/)

Comment: if you put your code on an online code editor, I would easy to help than